# How to give a javascript function and css style in struts2 property tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, struts2, struts

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
        $( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        });
  </script>
 <style type="text/css">
        .search_textbx
{
 background-image:url('/SalesPropeller/calendar.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:right;  

}

        </style>
```

In the above code,there is a javascript function and css style in which i am using those in `<input>` tag as shown below

```
<input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="search_textbx" size="15" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Here my question is i have struts2 tags and when i am using the same `id="startDate"` and `class="search_textbx"` in the below code,it is showing an error.I am completely new to struts2 so any help will be appreciated.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="html" uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" %>
<%@taglib prefix="bean" uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" %>
<html:html>
<body>
    <td style="padding-left:50px;">Lead Date </td>
    <td><html:text property="leadDate" size="17.5"/></td>
    <td><html:errors property="leadDate" /></td>
</body>
</html:html>
```

Comment: are you using struts1 ??

Comment: This isn't Struts 2, this is Struts 1. You'll get a lot of errors using what you have there under Struts 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the id/class to the td element and change the css/js to select the input inside the td.

jsp:

```
<td id='startDate'><html:text property="leadDate" size="17.5"/></td>
<td class='search_textbx'><html:text property="leadDate" size="17.5"/></td>
```

css:

```
.search_textbx input
{
 background-image:url('/SalesPropeller/calendar.jpg');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:right;  
}
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
        $( "#startDate input" ).datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In struts2 we can use cssStyle attribute in struts2 tag like this...

`<s:a href="%{LogOut}" cssStyle="search_textbx">
<small>&nbsp;LogOut&nbsp;</small>
</s:a>`

> `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>`

What you are using its struts1 i belive check this link [Using Struts 2 Tags](https://struts.apache.org/docs/using-struts-2-tags.html)

```
<td style="padding-left:50px;">Lead Date </td>
<td id="yourID"><s:text value="leadDate" size="17.5" cssStyle="search_textbx"></s:text></td>
<td id="yourID"><s:actionerror value="leadDate" cssStyle="search_textbx"></s:actionerror></td>
```

Comment: In S2 you can use the `style` attribute; it's aliased to `cssStyle`. But OP clearly isn't using Struts 1.